# Gracefully handle missing gradle definitions (use default values if definition is missing)

Tags: android, gradle

I usually do following in my projects:

1) define a versions.gradle file, e.g.:

```
ext {

    setup = [
        compileSdk: 28,
        enableDataBinding: true,
        minSdk    : 16,
        targetSdk : 28
    ]

    androidx = [
        supportv4: "1.0.0",
        appcompat: "1.0.0",
        cardview: "1.0.0",
        viewpager: "1.0.0",
        material: "1.0.0"
    ]

}
```

2) I add this versions file to my *projects* gradle file:

```
apply from: './versions.gradle'
```

3) I use the versions from the file in all my project gradle files for consistant library versions, like e.g.:

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${androidx.appcompat}"
```

**Question**

How can I handle this gracefully in open source libraries I use? I want that if someone checks out my library and adds the library directly to his projects, that some default version is provided so that this line `implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${androidx.appcompat}"` won't throw any error (`${androidx.appcompat}` should be replaced by `1.0.0` e.g. in this case).

Is there some way to solve this easily? I want that the version file is used if available and a fallback version is used otherwise...

Comment: You can use **elvis operator** to replace default version if defined version not found like this : `implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${androidx.appcompat ?: 1.0.0}"`

Comment: Thanks, that's the perfect solution. Better than some if in my gradle file and defining all missing definitions. One thing though, the number must be put in `'`

Comment: Yah, just **copy pasted** it.. so missed that !

Comment: No problem, could find this out myself ;-) Just write it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying **Elvis operator** for placing **default value** can do that trick, so replacing it with operator like below works :

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${androidx.appcompat ?: 'default value here'}"
```

More from [**here**](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html).